# Rewiring charger plug

Tags: electrical, wiring, battery

I've got a mains charger for some battery powered clippers which had has the cable cut clean through.

It's not a standard charger fitting, so I'm keen to repair it.

The cable consists of two wires, which are clearly marked + and - at the end where they plug into the clippers, but since it's such a clean cut I have no idea which wire is which at the plug end.

I gather if I wire them the wrong way round I'll run the risk of frying the battery - is there any way to work out which should connect to which?

The plug is a double insulated one that doesn't come apart, but I can wire on another plug if needs be

Comment: [Edit] in Pictures, please. The cable is the DC one from the charger to the device, not a mains cable? And this isn't something you picked out of a dumpster which might have been cut to remove it from service after determining that it was unsafe?

Comment: You mention that the cut is clean, but is there enough cable on both sides to see which conductor might be which?  Generally if you look closely, there is a stripe or embossed ribbing or printing that will indicate which side is which.

Comment: use a multimeter or even a loose LED to determine polarity of the charger end, then match to the marks on the clipper end.

Comment: To add to what @Chris O said strip the wire back an inch and notice if one is a different color, you may get lucky if not a little rib on 1 side+

Comment: @ChrisO unfortunately not - there's plenty on the plug side but the cut is directly where the cable joins the part that plugs into the clippers - I've had to cut away some of the moulded plastic to access the wires.

Comment: @Ecnerwal will add some pictures when I've got it to hand. And no, it's not been intentionally cut

Comment: @dandavis how do I do this safely with a multimeter? I do have one I can get hold of, have only used it on auto electrics before though so this is a bit new

Comment: peel back the insulation, measure voltage. if the number is negative the red lead is too, otherwise black is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Use the multimeter in continuity or resistance mode to determine which clipper plug wire connects to the positive terminal of the clipper plug (usually this will be the wire closest to the positive terminal, but make sure)

Then use the multimeter in voltage mode to find the positive terminal of the supply wire.   now you know which wires need to connect.

Usually when faced with a damaged low voltage appliance plug
I carve it until I have exposed the solder terminals where the
wire connects, then reconnect the wire there,
re-build the plug body using hot glue, and cover the whole in heat-shrink tubing.

Comment: Sugru is also good for replacing some of the strain relief that you inevitably carve away.